# Tensorflow - cant find dnn [OP:CudnnRNN]

Tags: python, tensorflow

so when i try to run the following code
import numpy as np

```
import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import time
from tensorflow import keras

def build_model1():
    macro_data = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None, 3)) 
    
    whole_seq_output, final_memory_state, final_carry_state = layers.LSTM(16,
                                                                          dropout=.95,
                                                                          input_shape=(None,3),
                                                                          return_sequences=True, 
                                                                          return_state=True)(macro_data)   
    
    SDF_Network = tf.keras.Model(
                            inputs=[macro_data],
                            outputs=[whole_seq_output],
                            name="SDF_Network"
                            )         
    
    return SDF_Network
temp = np.array([[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]])

SDF_Network = build_model1()
SDF_Network([temp])
```

I get the following error

```
UnknownError: Fail to find the dnn implementation. [Op:CudnnRNN]
```

but it only happens on LSTM layers, so I think its a GPU problem. So I re-installed CUDA 11.2 and cudnn 8.2 for my Tensorflow 2.5 and set the environment paths as well as copying the cudnn files into the CUDA folder and still everything is breaking.

I also tried adding in the following lines like other posts suggested

```
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], enable=True)
```

still nothing, furthermore i tested if Cuda is working with

```
tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()
tf.test.is_gpu_available(cuda_only=False, min_cuda_compute_capability=None)
```

and they both wring True. Here's my installation process.

```
#conda create --name TF-25-5 python=3.8
#conda install -c conda-forge numpy==1.19.5 
#conda install pandas
#conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib
#conda install tensorflow-gpu==2.5.0
#conda install tensorflow-datasets 
#conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow-hub
#pip install wrds
#pip install prettytables
#conda install -c conda-forge gin-config
#pip install tensorflow_addons
#pip install tensorflow-text
```

Comment: I am not able to produce this issue on a GPU colab.I think this somehow indicate its a environment issue. Can you try to create new virtual environment and try again?

Answer (score 1):

It was a very odd error. When I pip installed tensorflow-text it broke my cudnn installation. I had to conda install cudnn in order to make it work again.

Answer (score 0):

- Exactly the same things, better you uninstall the cudnn and install
  it back.
- please make sure you install the Cuda toolkit correct    version
  which is compatible with TensorFlow.